# Magento2 Media path in .phtml file

Tags: php, magento2, magento-2.0

I have tried lots of option in magento2 to find the media path URL

How can i find the media path URL in template.

I have try

```
$object_manager = Magento\Core\Model\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$dir = $object_manager->get('Magento\App\Dir');
$mediaUrl = $dir->getDir(\Magento\App\Dir::MEDIA);
```

But it give me error class not found. I have search and found the one solution to create function in block file but there are so many places i want to use the media path in my design

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the best answer is here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/235561/39707

Answer (score 9):

This is how you get the media path from inside a block or template.

```
$this->getUrl('pub/media')
```

Comment: it is giving me with store name... possible to get direct media file name e.g www.website.com/media/file.jpg

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to get media in PHTML is:

```
$block->getViewFileUrl('images/myimage.png');
```

Comment: This returns pub/static not pub/media

Comment: this is what most people actually want, the images folder in pub/static/ for your module/theme

Comment: Use module name if the image is in the custom module. For ex: $block->getViewFileUrl('Magento_Checkout::cvv.png')

Answer (score 4):

Usage of Object Manager is discouraged as per Magento's coding standards. In a template file, we can get the media URL using the following code:

```
$this->helper('\Magento\Cms\Helper\Wysiwyg\Images')->getBaseUrl()
```

As per the Magento's recommendation, the document root of your website should be outside `pub` directory during development and it should be inside `pub` directory when moved to production.

Hence we cannot hard code the `pub` directory while getting media URL in the template files. The above code will give you the correct media URL irrespective of your document root location.

Answer (score 3):

```
//Case 1: $objectManager outside magento
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;    
include('your-path-to-/app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();


//Case 2: $objectManager inside magento
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$mediaDir = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList')->getPath('media');
$mediaUrl = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);


// Case 3: Inside model
public function __construct(
\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context, 
\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList $directory_list, 
\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $url, 
array $data = []) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $this->directory_list = $directory_list;  
    $this->url = $url;  
}
$this->directory_list->getRoot();//root folder path
$this->directory_list->getPath('media');//media folder path
$this->url->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
```

It worked fine for me.

Answer (score 3):

Try to get it by using StoreManagerInterface

```
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

protected $storeManager;

public function __construct(
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
)
{
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
}
```

Now get media url using

```
$mediaUrl = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it try with below code:

```
$object_manager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$dir = $object_manager->get('Magento\App\Dir');

$mediaUrl = $dir->getDir(\Magento\App\Dir::MEDIA);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two way's to get the media Path in PHTML file:

**First Way**

```
    $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $storeManager = $om->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
    var_dump($storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA));
```

**Second Way**

index.php

contains:

```
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
```

One could do something like:

```
$mediaPath = MAGENTO_ROOT.'/pub/media/';
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, in my case, this worked:

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
    $store = $storeManager->getStore();
    $mediaUrl = $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`$baseurl=$block->getUrl();`

Returns your baseurl inside phtml.

Answer (score 0):

in your block inject StoreManagerInterface

```
namespace Altravista\Carousel\Block;
use Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageBuilder;

class Product extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    public $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        array $data = []
    )
    {    
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }


    public function getMediaUrl(){
       return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
    }

}
```

in your phtml call the block

```
$productBlock = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Altravista\Carousel\Block\Product');
```

and the method

```
$imageUrl = $media_url. 'catalog/product' . $product->getImage();
```